# install packages in virtual environment with pipenv from an environment.yml file

Tags: python, conda, pipenv, virtual-environment, pipfile

i'm getting started with pipenv, however, I want to reproduce a project of someone else who worked with conda. I have the corresponding environment.yml file at hand and want to load the required packages into a virtual environment using pipenv install. Of course I could do this manually one by one, but I wonder if there is a more sophisticated way of transforming the environment.yml file into either a pipfile or a requirement.txt file, from which pipenv install would also be able to load the packages in an automated fashion. 
thanks,
Olmo

Answer (score 2):

The way i solved this issue, was to rename the "environment.yml" which is generated by the conda package manager into "requirements.txt" and replace "=" by "==" in order to comply with the different syntax in pipenv. Also, the "environment.yml" file specifies the python version used for the project. This line must be deleted, since the python version is defined by the command `pipenv --python x.x`

Then I executed `pipenv -r install requirements.txt`

by doing so I avoided copy-pasting all the required packages from the environment.yml file into the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Make a file with the name requirements.txt which will include all the names of the packages which you want to install such that each package's name is on a single line.

Then run the command below from the location of the requirements.txt file in your local system:

Step 1: Switch to your environment using the command **conda activate environmentname** (for windows) or **source activate environmentname** (for Linux/MacOS). Once switched it will show your environment name inside parenthesis before the command.

Step 2:
Switch to the local directory (containing requirements.txt) staying inside your environment and run the following command:

**pip install -r requirements.txt**

This will help also:
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/

Comment: wouldnt this install the packages to my system python? As far as I understand the advantage of pipenv install is that this command would install the packages into a virtual environment created by 'pipenv shell'

Comment: I have edited my answer for your help. Maybe it helps now.

Comment: Maybe there is little missunderstanding. I do not use conda and I would like to avoid installing it. But can I use the 'pip install - r requirements.txt.' command inside an activated virtual environment created via 'pipenv shell'?

Comment: pipenv install [package names] . Write all the names of the packages you want to install.

Answer (score -1):

`environment.yml` is a file generate by package manager `conda`. While, `pipenv` is based on package manger `pip`.

AFAIK, it's impossible. `pip` and `conda`  are different tools, and

- they use different format in the generated environment file.
- The package formats supported by them are different
- The cloud hosts for the package distribution are different as well.